# Running top and free-m commands in parallel

Tags: linux, memory, process

I am trying to write a simple script that continuously monitors memory usage of a certain process. So I am trying to use 'top' with grep command to capture the memory usage of a certain process, as well as running free -m command and writing their outputs to text files.

```
top | grep --line-buffered -i process_name >> /home/output_txt1 &
while (1)
   free -m >> /home/output_txt2
   sleep 2
end &
```

However, when I run the commands, I get

> - Suspended (tty output) top | grep --line-buffered -i process_name >> /home/output_txt1 &

What am I doing wrong and how can I implement what I want? Knowing that I also tried using 'watch' before using the while loop and it didn't work also.

Comment: From `man top`:
-b : Batch mode operation
Starts top in "Batch mode", which could be useful for sending output from top to other programs or to a file.
In this mode, top will not  accept  input and runs until the iterations limit you've set with the '-n' command-line option or until killed.

You may give -b option a try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I used -b and now; top command works with no errors.

However, what I intended from the script doesn't happen, I find that the top command it continuously run and correctly write to the file while the "free -m" command runs ONLY one time. Is it something like that "top" command hijacks the process and doesn't allow the "while" loop to be executed again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told in my comment, from `man top`:

> -b : Batch mode operation
>               Starts top in âBatch modeâ, which could be useful for sending output from top to other programs or to a file.  In this mode, top will not  accept  input and runs until the iterations limit youâve set with the â-nâ command-line option or until killed.

and also:

> -n : Number of iterations limit as:  -n number
>               Specifies the maximum number of iterations, or frames, top should produce before ending.

I don't understand exactly what you want to do, but you should check if the below script fullfill your requirements:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
OUT_TOP="${DIR}/out_top"
OUT_FREE="${DIR}/out_free"
echo "$(date) Reset" > "${OUT_TOP}"
echo "$(date) Reset" > "${OUT_FREE}"

while true
do
  date >> "${OUT_TOP}"
  date >> "${OUT_FREE}"
  top -b -n 1 | grep --line-buffered -i apache >> "${OUT_TOP}"
  free -m >> "${OUT_FREE}"
  sleep 2
done
```

Infinite loop is coming from [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-infinite-loop/).

When I tested, it gave a result close to what you may be searching:

```
[so46072643] ./topandfree &
[1] 27313
[so46072643] sleep 8
[so46072643] kill 27313
[so46072643] for f in `ls ./out*`; do printf "\n%s\n<<--\n" $f; cat $f; echo "-->>"; done

./out_free
<<--
Wed Sep  6 12:54:54 CEST 2017 Reset
Wed Sep  6 12:54:54 CEST 2017
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7985       6808       1177          0        263       1400
-/+ buffers/cache:       5144       2840
Swap:         8031        117       7914
Wed Sep  6 12:54:56 CEST 2017
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7985       6808       1176          0        263       1400
-/+ buffers/cache:       5145       2840
Swap:         8031        117       7914
Wed Sep  6 12:54:59 CEST 2017
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7985       6808       1176          0        263       1400
-/+ buffers/cache:       5145       2840
Swap:         8031        117       7914
Wed Sep  6 12:55:01 CEST 2017
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7985       6808       1176          0        263       1400
-/+ buffers/cache:       5144       2840
Swap:         8031        117       7914
Wed Sep  6 12:55:04 CEST 2017
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7985       6808       1177          0        263       1400
-/+ buffers/cache:       5144       2840
Swap:         8031        117       7914
Wed Sep  6 12:55:06 CEST 2017
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7985       6808       1177          0        263       1400
-/+ buffers/cache:       5144       2841
Swap:         8031        117       7914
[1]+  Terminated              ./topandfree
-->>

./out_top
<<--
Wed Sep  6 12:54:54 CEST 2017 Reset
Wed Sep  6 12:54:54 CEST 2017
 4747 apache    20   0  171m 2068  436 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4748 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4750 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4751 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4752 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4753 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4754 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4755 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
Wed Sep  6 12:54:56 CEST 2017
 4747 apache    20   0  171m 2068  436 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4748 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4750 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4751 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4752 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4753 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4754 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4755 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
Wed Sep  6 12:54:59 CEST 2017
 4747 apache    20   0  171m 2068  436 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4748 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4750 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4751 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4752 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4753 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4754 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4755 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
Wed Sep  6 12:55:01 CEST 2017
 4747 apache    20   0  171m 2068  436 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4748 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4750 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4751 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4752 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4753 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4754 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4755 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
Wed Sep  6 12:55:04 CEST 2017
 4747 apache    20   0  171m 2068  436 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4748 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4750 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4751 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4752 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4753 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4754 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4755 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
Wed Sep  6 12:55:06 CEST 2017
 4747 apache    20   0  171m 2068  436 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4748 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4750 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4751 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4752 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4753 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4754 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
 4755 apache    20   0  171m 2072  440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 httpd
-->>
[so46072643]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it works, thanks very much.

The mistake I had is that I used "-b" without using "-n" argument. So, the top command hijacked the process and didn't end, so free -m command was never executed.